# How to import "ordinary" sas datasets via script?

Tags: sas

For some reason SAS refuses to read ordinary datasets. I try writing

```
Data test2;
set "/opt3/01_Dataleveranser/03_IBIS/Inläsning/IBIS3/IBIS3_Mikrodata_Tot220926.sas7bdat";
run;
```

And I get told that `ERROR: File IBIS.IBIS3_MIKRODATA_TOT220926.DATA does not exist.`

Strangely enough I absolutely know the filepath is correct. For instance this code works just fine:

```
PROC IMPORT 
DATAFILE="/opt3/01_Dataleveranser/03_IBIS/Inläsning/IBIS3/IBIS3_Mikrodata_Tot_220907.xlsx"
OUT=WORK.test2
DBMS=xlsx 
REPLACE;
SHEET="Data";
GETNAMES=YES; 
DATAROW=2;
Run;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Someone must have changed the name of the file to generate a filename with mixed case letters.  SAS is only looking for files with lowercase letters.  On Windows it doesn't matter as the operating system does not distinguish between the two.  But on Unix files with different cased letters in the name are different physical files.

Answer (score 3):

I mailed the IT-department and SAS apparantly really hates capital letters in filenames. Changing uppercase letters to lowercase did resolve the problem. Of course I then ran into additional problems, but that wasn't the topic.

Comment: Filenames in Linux are case sensitive.  Not so in Windows.  SAS data set names correspond to operating system filenames.  In Linux/Win SAS normalizes data set names to lowercase operating system filenames.  Within SAS, data set names can be referenced with any upper/lower case combination.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard pointed out SAS always normalizes table names in Linux/Unix to lowercase. But your way of accessing a SAS table is not the usual one, I would say. Or in other words: if you first define a library and then access the table via the descriptor [library].[tablename] you can use uppercase and lowercase letters in any mix you want. But on the Linux/Unix level it will still be only in lowercase.

```
libname ibis "/opt3/01_Dataleveranser/03_IBIS/Inläsning/IBIS3/";

data test2;
set ibis.IBIS3_Mikrodata_Tot220926;
run;
```

Two additional notes:

1. The following three references to a SAS table are in fact always referencing the same identical table: <ibis.IBIS3_Mikrodata_Tot220926> and  <ibis.ibis3_mikrodata_tot220926> and <ibis.IBIS3_MIKRODATA_TOT220926>
2. You can change the name of a SAS table on the operating system level in Linux so that it will be accessible in SAS by its new name, but *only* if you use lowercase letters. As soon as you change a letter to uppercase you will not be able to see the table in SAS.